# CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL() crashing when i change the url

Tags: ios, cfstream

I am using the following code for load list from any ftp server:

```
    self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
        CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
    );

    assert(self.networkStream != nil);
    //[self.networkStream setProperty:@"ANONYMOUS" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
    //[self.networkStream setProperty:@"abc" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];
```

Its perfectly loading the list. Then i am showing the list in UITableView. Once the data is loaded i am closing the stream using this code :

```
if (self.networkStream != nil) {
        [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
        [self.networkStream close];
        self.networkStream = nil;
    }
```

When the user taps on any cell i am trying to load the list of that folder (if its a folder) otherwise i have to download the file from ftp server. For this i am using this code by changing the url :

```
          self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                           CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)

                                           );
   /* [self.networkStream setProperty:( id) kCFBooleanFalse
                             forKey:( NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection
     ];
    */
    assert(self.networkStream != nil);
    //[self.networkStream setProperty:@"ANONYMOUS" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
    //[self.networkStream setProperty:@"abc" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];
```

Buts its crashing on this line :

```
CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
```

giving **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** on this line. I am not able to figure out the reasons. Please Help me out.

Comment: Show us how the url is being initialised and what the url really is. I don't think this has anything to do with rest of the networking code.

Comment: To make sure the object is properly type casted, use self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) CFBridgingRelease(CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url));

Comment: url is working fine. I have tried it on every browser (Chrome,firefox and safari). I have tried this use self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) CFBridgingRelease(CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)); too. but its crashing

Comment: Browsers have several fall back mechanisms and ability to correct the URL. I need to see where the 'url' variable is coming from. If its EXC_BAD_ACCESS then  this pointer is paticularly flawed.

Comment: yes the issue was with url. i was creating the url ftp:/192.168.1.15:2121/abc/ but the actual url should be "ftp:// address" ftp://192.168.1.15:2121/abc/ "i was missing double slash". Thanks to Imran rahim and debuggerman.

Comment: I met the same problem. Any solution?